# hide everything except the first element with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a one lined way to hide all of a certain type of elements in one selector. I know you could do this:

```
$('p').hide();
$('p:first(or :eq(0)').show()
```

Possibly something like this:

```
$('p:eq(>0)')
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) will probably give the best performance:

```
$('p').slice(1).hide();
```

...where `1` is the second element in the results and `0` would be the first.  This is faster because it uses native methods instead of a custom filter.

Alternatively, you could use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('p:not(:first)').hide();

//or $('p').not(':first').hide();
```

Comment: works great thank you. Oh yeah your right, going to stick with the slice

Answer (score 6):

http://jsfiddle.net/x6DEY/

```
$("p").not(":first").hide();
```

This should work too but is ugly:

```
$("div:not(:first)").hide();
```